# PSU Clicks once then turns off

Tags: power-supply, troubleshooting, desktop-computer

I'm building a new pc & I got most of my parts today, figured I'd check for faulty components. Everything built and done, but when I jump my mobo my PSU clicks once and shuts down. I'm pretty sure it's the PSU as I used an old EVGA PSU jumper on it and the issue still persisted. Any ideas or is it RMA time? It's an FSP Flex atx 400w Gold

Comment: The behavior you describe sounds like a short.  Why are you "jumping" your PSU?

Comment: Because it did the same thing when plugged in to all of my components? Jumping the PSU is the only way of ensuring it's the power supply's fault by taking all the other components out of the picture. If EVGA is sending jumpers with their PSU's I don't see how it would be negative to try jumping my PSU.